# Save the circular crop image from Cropper

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image, blob

I'm using Cropper to crop the images in a circular shape from this example:
https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/master/examples/crop-a-round-image.html

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7hsr98w4/7/

That's how the cropped image looks like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

Then I use Ajax to send that blob to PHP to upload that image:

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var imgurl = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
    cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('avatar', blob);
        // Use `jQuery.ajax` method
        $.ajax('upload.php', {
            method: "POST",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('Upload error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This code could be found here:
https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#getcroppedcanvasoptions

In upload.php:

```
print_r($_FILES);
if(isset($_FILES['avatar']) and !$_FILES['avatar']['error']){
   file_put_contents("uploads/image.png", file_get_contents($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']));
}   
exit();
```

That's the `response` from `print_r($_FILES)`:

```
Array
(
    [avatar] => Array
        (
            [name] => blob
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php2BDA.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 2135
        )

)
```

When I `console.log()` `blob`, I get and `Object`:

```
Blob(2135) {size: 2135, type: "image/png"}
```

But when I view the image on the `uploads` folder, It's a rectangular image not circular.

Here is how it's previewed after cropping:
[image: Circular]
And that's how it's previewed on `uploads` folder:
[image: Rectangular]
Both images(previewed and saved) are 360x360.

How to save the cropped image in circular shape like how it's previewed after cropping?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add rounding box css for `.cropper-crop-box` also

```
.cropper-crop-box, .cropper-view-box {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

If you want circular view box you can use  this

```
.cropper-view-box {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #39f;
    outline: 0;
}
```

UPDATE:
Sorry I misunderstood your question actually what you wanted was pretty straightforward

You already have `getRoundedCanvas()` which gets you the rounded version of crop, so just need to use it in your ajax call like

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var imgurl = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();

    //only this line is changed
    getRoundedCanvas(cropper.getCroppedCanvas()).toBlob(function (blob) { 
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('avatar', blob);
        // Use `jQuery.ajax` method
        $.ajax('upload.php', {
            method: "POST",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('Upload error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That's already exist within my code not in the fiddle, The image is cropped in rounded shape and the preview blew it is circular, But when I save it with PHP it becomes rectangular

Answer (score 0):

I think that this function getroundedcanvas() doesn't exist with the jquery-cropper.js, if it was you, you have already done a great job with your function, I really needed it badly this is what I added and uploaded it with PHP.

```
case 'getCroppedCanvas':
      if (result) {
        // Upload cropped image to server if the browser supports `HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob`.
        // The default value for the second parameter of `toBlob` is 'image/png', change it if necessary.

        // Round
        var roundedCanvas = getRoundedCanvas(result);
        // Show
        $('img.MyImage').attr('src',roundedCanvas.toDataURL());
        var roundedBlob ;
        roundedCanvas.toBlob((blob) => {
          roundedBlob = blob;
        });
        result.toBlob((blob) => {
          const formData = new FormData();

          // Pass the image file name as the third parameter if necessary.
          formData.append('UploadPhoto', blob, 'profil.png' );
          formData.append('CircleBlob', roundedBlob, 'circle.png' );
          $.ajax(document.location.pathname, {
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success(response) {
              console.log(response);
              console.log('Upload success');
              $('#imgResizeModal').modal("hide");
            },
            error() {
              console.log('Upload error');
            },
          });
        }/*, 'image/png' */);
      }

      break;
```

Comment: Hi DevStudy and thanks for the contribution. Can you add some context to your code snippet so that it becomes clear where to insert it? Even better if you add a little explanation as well. Thanks and keep on stackoverflowing!

Comment: responding at the topic to get the crop form of the canvas and upload it in PHP, When you validate the crop you get the square form with the function getCroppedCanvas() using jQuery-cropper.js; and then  with the function getRoundedCanvas(result), you convert it to the circle.